# Downloading Images using BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to download images off of a site using bs4, the images are not jpeg or png so I think that bs4 is unable to find the image, I could be wrong about that as well.

Here's my code

```
#--- IMAGE --- NOT WORKING
        #Finds the image URL with the name of the product
        #done
        image = soup.find('img', attrs={'class':"image_container"})
        try: 
            image = image.get("src")
        except AttributeError:
            print("NO image FOUND")
            image = "NO image FOUND"
        if(image != "NO image FOUND"): #if the image is found 
            try:
                pos = image.index("?")
                image = "http:" + image[:pos]
            except ValueError:
                pass
            pathImg += name[:nameLength] # Truncates to 5 characters and adds to pathImg file
            if(generateFiles):
                download(image, pathImg) # Downloads image
            self.image = image # Exporting var to class global var
```

Heres an image of where the source is on the page
[Source Code for the image container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMdw.png)

Comment: The code is not reproducible. By looking at in, I would say that the `http:` in `image = "http:" + image[:pos]` can be deleted. Because the `src` should contain the protocoll.

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: here is the URL: https://www.americanmuscle.com/flowmaster-american-thunder-axleback-2015gt.html

Comment: first check `print( image )` and try this URL in web browser.

Comment: I agree with @samusa you create wrong url `http:https://...`